# How to resolve this in PHPUnit where it is asking me to set KERNEL_DIR in my phpunit.xml?

Tags: symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

Here is my phpunit.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
        colors="true"
        convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
        convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
        convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
        stopOnFailure="true"
        strict="true"
        bootstrap="./vendor/autoload.php">
    <testsuites>
        <php>
            <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app" />
            <ini name="display_errors" value="true"/>
        </php>
        <testsuite name="Functional Tests">
            <directory>./tests/src/myApp/AppBundle/functional</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./src/</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

Here is the test class

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class MyTest extends WebTestCase
{
    private $client;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->client = static::createClient();
    }
```

When running the test I get at the line in setUp:

> Either set KERNEL_DIR in your phpunit.xml according to
>   https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#your-first-functional-test
>   or override the WebTestCase::createKernel() method

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Move the `<php> ... </php>` out of the `<testsuites>...` block to it's own top-level.

Here's a trimmed down copy of my own main project:

```
<phpunit 
    bootstrap = "app/bootstrap_test.php"
    verbose = "true"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1" />
        <!-- <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="./app/" /> older-style -->
        <server name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="AppKernel" />
        <server name="SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER" value="weak" />
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="project.name">
            <directory suffix=".php">./src/*Bundle</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">./src/AppBundle</directory> -->
            <directory>./tests/App</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
```

Comment: You've put me on the right path with moving the php tag up a level... but now I am getting `Class "AppKernel" doesn't exist or cannot be autoloaded. Check that the KERNEL_CLASS value in phpunit.xml matches the fully-qualified class name of your Kernel`. It's situated in app/AppKernel.php, but the ones I've tried haven't worked.

Comment: You might want the older KERNEL_DIR line instead of KERNEL_CLASS. Or https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony3-upgrade/new-dir-structure has details on upgrading to Symfony 3.0+ style tests.

Comment: @Michael Replace with <server name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="App\Kernel" /> in phpunit.xml

Comment: If you're trying to run tests inside PhpStorm, it can't detect `phpunit.xml.dist` even if you set `KERNEL_CLASS` inside. So you'll have to copy  `phpunit.xml.dist`'s content inside `phpunit.xml` and PhpStorm will detect it when running tests. 
Another option is to set manually `KERNEL_CLASS` (and `DATABASE_URL` if asked) for each test/class configuration.