# Am I defining KERNEL_CLASS in the right place?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I am trying to run a basic functional test using WebTestCase in a Symfony 4 application. When I run my test, I get this output:

> 1)
>   Tests\Application\EndToEnd\AuthenticationTest::testAuthenticationMethodNotAllowed
>   RuntimeException: Class "App\Kernel" doesn't exist or cannot be
>   autoloaded. Check that the KERNEL_CLASS value in phpunit.xml matches
>   the fully-qualified class name of your Kernel or override the
>   Tests\Application\EndToEnd\AuthenticationTest::createKernel() method.

Trying to follow the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49142038/8252915), I edit `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xml` and add this line:

```
<server name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="AppKernel" />
```

and here's where it gets interesting: I still get the complaint about `App\Kernel` -- with the backslash -- being unavailable.

This tells me that I'm probably editing the wrong XML file, since my edited-in value doesn't contain a backslash. **In which XML file should I be adding my definition?**

Comment: Wich version of symfony 4 do you use ?

Comment: We're using Symfony 4.2.4.

Comment: You can defined your parameter into an env.test file i think this recipe can help you: https://github.com/symfony/recipes/tree/master/symfony/phpunit-bridge (automatically installed when install symfony/test-pack)

Comment: Thanks. How does one install this recipe?

Comment: I don't know what you have already installed, else run composer require test

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error while running tests via PHPStorm (they were working when running them manually). I had to set the "Default configuration file" to `/path/to/phpunit.xml`.

1. In Preferences, go to "Languages and Frameworks", "PHP" and then "Test Frameworks"
2. Ensure the appropriate interpreter is selected (in my case it's a remote interpreter to a Docker container)
3. Set the path of "Default configuration file" to your project's local `phpunit.xml` or `phpunit.xml.dist`

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I needed to create a phpunit.xml file in the **root level** of my project. Once the relevant XML was present there, this sorted itself out.

Comment: In my project, the file `phpunit.xml` wasn't there, but `phpunit.xml.dist` was. Using the file that was already there worked just fine for me.